# Apache POI check color to green,red,blue java. Color comparison

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to check the 11th cell's color in every row and make some action if it is needed color. I do this, but it doesn't work

```
short blueColorIndex = 64;
short redColorIndex = 0;//change
short yellowColorIndex = 0;//change

short cellColorIndex = row.getCell(11).getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColor();

if (cellColorIndex==blueColorIndex){
    System.out.println("make action 1");

} else if (cellColorIndex==yellowColorIndex){
    
    System.out.println("make action 2");

} else if (cellColorIndex==redColorIndex){
    System.out.println("3");
    
}
```

Comment: Excel cell interiors have pattern fill. The foreground color is the color of the pattern and the background color is the color behind the pattern. Cells having color fill have solid foreground pattern. So only fill foreground color is of interest. The fill background color can be neglected.

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned in [the documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell-int-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.MissingCellPolicy-), the index of the `getCell` method is 0-based.
It means that in order to retrieve the 11th cell, you have to use the index 10

Comment: My question is not about indexing